Weird Lag when offsetting Navigation Stack
I have really unwanted behavior with NavigationStack. When I try to offset the whole NavigationStack the NavigationTitle jumps like 10 pixels when offsetting it down
Here is the code. It is really minimal. I have the "hello" which I use to drag everything up and down:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var offset = CGSize.zero

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
           Text("TEst")
                .navigationTitle("Home")
        }
        .offset(y:offset.height)
        
        Text("Hello")
            .highPriorityGesture(
                DragGesture(minimumDistance: 1, coordinateSpace: .named("Grid"))
                    .onChanged { gesture in
                        offset = gesture.translation
                    }
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        withAnimation{
                            offset = .zero
                        }
                    }
            )
    }
}

Video: https://streamable.com/siaovs
In the Video it first shows that when dragging it up, it only has a delay and then moves smoothly. After that I try to drag down where you can see the Title jump.

NavugationStack isnt meant to be offset. It takes over the whole thing.

@loremipsum How can I then achieve something like this? I want fullscreencover which I can dismiss by dragging it down. So basically a sheet which is full screen.

There is fullScreenCover and sheet as built in tools. You can try an overlay.
